# Plotting square() and sawtooth() in Octave

Tags: plot, octave, freemat

I was trying to plot a square wave and a saw-tooth wave in Octave, but it gave an error saying

```
>>>error: 'sawtooth' undefined near line 17 column 6
error: 'square' undefined near line 17 column 6
>>>error: 'x1' undefined near line 17 column 21
error: evaluating argument list element number 2
>>>error: 'x2' undefined near line 18 column 21
error: evaluating argument list element number 2
```

Then I read up on internet, and came to know that I have to install some packages. I installed the necessary packages and also their respective dependencies. In spite of doing that, it did not make a difference. The same error persisted. I then installed all the packages from the online repositories. Again that made no difference.

I ran the same code in Matlab and it worked!  (I know it comes bundled with all the packages).

But I don't really get the problem I am facing in Octave. I use the QtOctave interface and there is a option there to install packages. Is there some way to check for installed packages? Are they actually getting installed?

I tried the same code in FreeMat and it gave some error there too.

Here is my code:

```
% program to plot a saw tooth and square wave
fs = 10000;
t = 0:1/fs:1.5;
x1 = sawtooth(2*pi*50*t);
x2 = square(2*pi*50*t);
subplot(211);plot(t,x1);axis([0 0.2 -1.2 1.2]);
xlabel('Time (sec)');ylabel('Amplitude');title('Sawtooth Periodic Wave');
subplot(212);plot(t,x2);axis([0 0.2 -1.2 1.2]);
xlabel('Time (sec)');ylabel('Amplitude');title('Square Periodic Wave');
set(gcf,'Color',[1 1 1]);
```

Please help me to get this code to work on Octave.

Comment: see Octave's FAQ "[I have installed a package but still get a `foo undefined` error](http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#I_have_installed_a_package_but_still_get_a_.22foo_undefined.22_error)"

Answer (score 3):

Works for me. See https://saturnapi.com/fullstack/plotting-square-and-sawtooth-in-octave

If you're using Ubuntu, make sure to install the necessary package a la

```
sudo apt-get -q -y install octave-signal
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you actually loaded the packages of interest? Even though the packages are installed, they may not be loaded into your particular Octave session. You can do this by typing `pkg load <package_name>` at the Octave prompt replace `<package_name>` by the corresponding paccage name.

Comment: PS: `pkg list` will list the packages installed. The packages loaded are marked with a `*` symbol.